# Executando comando com outro usuário dentro de um shell script

Tags: linux, shell, bash

Tenho um shell script que preciso executar alguns comandos com um usuário do linux, e alguns outros comandos com outro usuário.

Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
#!/bin/bash

  echo 'rodando com usuário A'
  comando1
  comando2
  comando3

  echo 'Rodando com Usuário B'
  sudo su comando4
```

O problema é que gostaria de realizar todos os comandos no mesmo script. Mas assim que o comando com o segundo usuário é iniciado, uma nova sessão `bash` é iniciada.
É possível executar comandos com 2 usuários diferentes no mesmo script?

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar o [`su`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/su) do seguinte modo para fazer isso no *shell script*:

```sh
su -c "comando" -s /bin/sh nomedoUsuario
```

Onde o parâmetro `-c` especifica passar um único comando ao shell e `-s` é utilizado para especificar com qual *shell* chamaremos o comando.

Uma outra forma para fazer isso é através do uso do [`sudo`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) do seguinte modo:

```sh
sudo -H -u nomedoUsuario bash -c "comando"
```

O parâmetro `-h` é uma política de segurança que permite definir a variável de ambiente `$HOME` para o usuário especificado(*root é por padrão*). `-u` especifica o usuário a executar o comando.

```sh
  #!/bin/bash

  echo 'rodando com usuário A'
  sudo -H -u nomedoUsuario bash -c "Foo" 
  sudo -H -u nomedoUsuario bash -c "Bar" 

  echo 'Rodando com Usuário B'
  sudo -H -u nomedoUsuario bash -c "Baz"
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilizo o comando `runuser`. Sintaxe básica: `runuser -l usuario -c comando`.

Os comandos abaixo servem de teste, mostrando qual o usuário atual e o PID do bash:

```
whoami && echo $$
sleep 2
runuser -l usuario1 -c "whoami && echo $$"
sleep 2
runuser -l usuario2 -c "whoami && echo $$"
```

Para mais informações rode o comando `man runuser`.

Comment: Bem apreciado sua ajuda, irei testar também sua sugestão. Obrigado.

Answer (score -2):

consegui resolver com esse comando:

```
su otrs /opt/otrs/bin/otrs.Daemon.pl start -s /usr/bin/perl
```